# Nginx resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, debian, zend-framework3

I have a Debian 9 server with nginx installed.
I also installed ZendFramework 3.

Now I wanted to change the default document root, which is /var/www/html, to my Zend Project.

My index file is located in: /var/www/example.com/module/Application/view/application/index/index.phtml

My /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 81 default_server;
    listen [::]:81 default_server;

    root /var/www/example.com/module/Application/view/application/index;

    index index.phtml index.php;
 }
```

When I visit the site, the index.phtml gets downloaded and Google-Chrome outputs this in the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream
```

Do I have an error in a config file? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nginx doesn't recognise the mime type of the .phtml file extension, so you need to add it to your config.

The file to add it to is usually found at `/etc/nginx/mime.types`

Comment: I hate it when someone gives a proper answer, and then the OP makes himself "forget" about accepting the answer... so I up- voted your answer.